# How do I reference json schema emitted by wepack?

Tags: json, webpack, jsonschema

I work on a Electron project that uses Webpack. I use json schemas, configured like this:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.schema.json$/,
        type: "asset/resource",
        generator: {
          filename: "schemas/[name].json",
        },
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So, if I have somewhere in my sources file `some-config.schema.json` that looks like this:

```
{
  "$id": "/schemas/some-config",
  "$ref": "/schemas/other-config"
}
```

It is emitted as `http://localhost:1212/dist/schemas/some-config.schema.json`. Notice `1212` — this is port number that is configured dynamically by different tools that configure the build, so I can't even know that path when I write code or schemas.

However, the `$ref` above doesn't work:

> Problems loading reference 'file:///schemas/other-config': Unable to load schema from '/schemas/other-config': Failed to fetch.

I would want for it to load `http://localhost:1212/dist/schemas/other-config.schema.json`. How do I set up this reference?

Answer (score 1):

The value of `$ref` is a URI, and not a URL. This matters because the URI is not necessarily "network addressable", aka, not a real network address.

The value of `$id` is an identifier only.

When a JSON Schema parser gets a value in `$id` which is a relative URI, if it can't determine a base URI to resolve to an absolute URI, then it should make one up. So, pretend it makes one up, or uses `https://example.com`.

So, when you use an `$id` value of `/schemas/other-config`, we can pretend it's prefixed with `https://example.com`, and so resolves to `https://example.com/schemas/other-config`. The same is true for `/schemas/some-config`.

When a JSON Schema processes the schema you've provided, it should first be using the URI resolution process, matching up references with it's index of `$id` values to schemas.

Essentially, set up correctly, your schema files could be located anywhere, as long as they have the correct `$id` values, and you've loaded them in to the implementation you're using.

Comment: This sounds like a valid answer about the core principle, but I'm just confused and a bit stupid. Could I ask you to please explain it using the example from my question — what do I need to change, either in source or destination schema, to may the references work?

Comment: Part of the problem is I don't know which implementation you're using to do the validation. Unless you want to also host/serve the schema files, you don't need to load and bundle them through webpack in order to use URI references. Given I don't know the implementation you're using, here's the docs for how to properly create and load multiple schemas, for the most popular implementation: https://ajv.js.org/guide/combining-schemas.html#combining-schemas-with-ref

Comment: But I'm actually hosting and serving the schema files on the localhost. As I said, webpack puts the schema on `http://localhost:1212/dist/schemas/some-config.schema.json`, and then `monaco-yaml` plugin downloads it from this address.

Comment: You don't NEED to serve them on localhost to get this to work. It looks like `monaco-yaml` uses `yaml-language-server` to do most of the work. Let me ping the maintainer to come help.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't set up it otherwise: https://github.com/remcohaszing/monaco-yaml/issues/175

Comment: Unfortunatly, I'm not able to help you further here. The expected method is as per documented in the ajv guide I linked to previously: provide all schemas with URI, which should be resolved. If you're having problems with how monaco-yaml accepts schemas, it might be best to raise an issue on the repo.

Comment: So, summing it up — given the conditions set up in my question, it's impossible to force yaml schemas to be downloaded from `http://localhost:1212/dist/` using reference links, correct?

Comment: I don't know. It looks like it could be possible, but the port number thing poses an issue. You would need to dynamically serve the JSON with the port number, because you can't know it at build time (you say). I'm not seeing the whole picture of what you're doing, and it seems like it would take some effort to fully replicate your setup. You're welcome to come ask your question on the JSON Schema Slack server, but I think we've reached the end of the line on StackOverflow.